$\liminf(2g-|f_n-f|)=2g$ in the Dominated Convergence Theorem
Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of extended real-valued measureble function on a set $X$ and let $f$ be an extended real-valued measurable function such that $f_n\to f$ a.e. in $X$.
If exists $g\in L^1$ sich that $|f_n|\le g$ a.e. in $X$ Then $$\int_X|f_n-f|\;d\mu\to 0$$
I must provein detail that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} (2g-|f_n-f|)=2g$$
My attempt 1
Since the limit of $f_n$ exists a-e. in $X$ and is equal to $f$, then also the limit of $(2g-|f_n-f|)$ exists a.e. in $X$ and then $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}(2g-|f_n-f|)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(2g-|f_n-f|)=2g-\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n-f|=2g-|\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n-f|=2g$$

Is this approach correct or do we need to use some inferior limt property?

My attempt 2
$$\liminf(2g-|f_n-f|)=\\2g+\liminf(-|f_n-f|)=\\ 2g-\limsup|f_n-f|=\\2g-\lim|f_n-f|=\\ 2g-|\lim f_n-f|=2g$$

There is nothing to prove. This sequence has a $\lim$ and you can very quickly see what that limit is. Your attempt 1 is correct.

If this is part of the proof of the LDCT, then you're working with $\liminf$ to take advantage of Fatou's lemma. The point is just that $f_n \to f$ a.e. as $n\to\infty$, so $|f_n - f| \to 0$ a.e. as $n\to\infty$; that's just the definition of the limit.
